# how to run python ('base' : conda) script file using git bash

Tags: python, git, git-bash

I am a window user. I used to write python script using Visual Studio having python interpreter with
**('base' : conda)**. I want to run a python script file (scipt_1.py) using git bash with the following command:

```
./script_1.py
```

But I get an error stated that:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory
```

script_1.py file is although present on the current directory.

So please help me to run this file using Git bash command line.

Comment: What do you get with `python script_1.py`?

Comment: print("Hello world") in main function and calling that function in a script_1.py file

Comment: I mean try to run your script in the console with `python script_1.py`

Comment: yeah  that's working. Thanks @po.pe for your help